# R: How to make a frequency distribution for categorical (factor) variables?

Tags: r, categorical-data, frequency-distribution

(a)  Investigate the frequency distributions for the categorical predictors.

I have tried the below but can’t seem to get it to work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
library(mlbench)
data(Soybean)
str(Soybean)

soy = Soybean[,-c(1,2)]

> table(soy)
Error in table(soy) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements

par(mfrow = c(17, 2))
for (i in 1:34) {
  hist(soy[ ,i], xlab = names(soy[i]), main = paste(names(soy[i]), "Histogram"), col="deepskyblue")  
}
Error in hist.default(soy[, i], xlab = names(soy[i]), main = paste(names(soy[i]),  : 
  'x' must be numeric

> barplot(prop.table(table(soy)))
Error in table(soy) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your title clearly indicates that you have a factor/ you use barplots on factors and not histograms. ie `barplot(table(soy[,i]))`

Comment: I just tried this and fully expanded the plot window but it says figure margins are too large.

Comment: according to the question, do you need the plots or the results?

Comment: try `barplot(table(soy[,1]))`

Comment: Here is the full question: "(a)  Investigate the frequency distributions for the categorical predictors. Are any of the distributions degenerate in the ways discussed earlier in this chapter?" It doesn't specify, but since a similar question on this assignment used plots, I figured this one would also need a plot. But thinking on it, the results would probably be just as effective

Comment: `barplot(table(soy[,1]))` gave me the same error :/

Comment: try run `dev.off()` then run `barplot(table(soy[,1]))`

Comment: Well, it plotted the bar plot, but it only shows results for 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes, soy[,1] has only 0's and 1's. Hope this solves your problem

Comment: oh, that's right! Okay, yes it does. Thank you!